# how to extract text from anchor tag inside div class in r

Tags: r

I am trying to fetch text from anchor tag, which is embedded in div tag. Following is the link of website `http://mmb.moneycontrol.com/forum-topics/stocks-1.html

The text I want to extract is `Mawana Sugars`

```
<a href="/forum-topics/stocks/mawana-sugars-245010.html" class="op_bld16 anch_pb7">Mawana Sugars</a>
```

So I want to extract all the stocks names listed on this website and description of it.

Here is my attempt to do it in R

```
doc <- htmlParse("http://mmb.moneycontrol.com/forum-topics/stocks-1.html")
xpathSApply(doc,"//div[@class='clearfix PR PB5']//text()",xmlValue)
```

But, it does not return anything. How can I do it in R?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer is essentially the same as the one I just gave [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44002324).

The data is dynamically loaded, and cannot be retrieved directly from the html. But, looking at "Network" in Chrome DevTools for instance, we can find a nicely formatted JSON at http://mmb.moneycontrol.com/index.php?q=topic/ajax_call&section=get_messages&offset=&lmid=&isp=0&gmt=cat_lm&catid=1&pgno=1

To get you started:

```
library(jsonlite)
dat <- fromJSON("http://mmb.moneycontrol.com/index.php?q=topic/ajax_call&section=get_messages&offset=&lmid=&isp=0&gmt=cat_lm&catid=1&pgno=1")
```

Output looks like:

```
dat[1:3, c("msg_id", "user_id", "topic", "heading", "flag", "price", "message")]
#     msg_id      user_id    topic  heading flag
# 1 47730730    liontrade     NMDC   Stocks  APR
# 2 47730726 agrawalknath Glenmark Glenmark  APR
# 3 47730725      bissy91  Infosys   Stocks  APR
#                                                  price
# 1 Price when posted :  BSE: Rs. 127.90 NSE: Rs. 128.15
# 2                 Price when posted :  NSE: Rs. 714.10
# 3 Price when posted :  BSE: Rs. 956.50 NSE: Rs. 955.00
#                                                                                                                        message
# 1                                                                         There is no mention of dividend in the announcement.
# 2                        Eagerly Waiting for 670 to 675 to BUY second phase of Buying in Cash Delivery. Already Holding @ 800.
# 3 6 ✂ ✂--Don t Pay High Brokerage While Trading. Take Delivery Free & Rs 20 to trade in any size - Join Today . goo.gl/hDqLnm
```

Comment: Thanks a ton for your answer. Just one question,how did you extract that link?

Comment: I opened Chrome DevTools (Ctrl + Shift + I) and looked at the Network tab, then hit F5 and sort by `Type` to filter out images and the like. Sometimes what you look for can be directly found in the `Sources` tab

Comment: Got it.. What if I want to extract text of widget on that website?

Comment: If it's Flash, I know no easy way. If it's JS, it's "easy" if you can find the data source that is called by the widget, like here. Otherwise, once I scripted with Selenium because I couldn't find a better way (and it was ugly and slow)

Comment: on this website `http://mmb.moneycontrol.com/` there is sentifi widget which displays trending Indian stocks on social media. How can I extract that text?