# Scraping a table from a website using R (Rvest).. or VBA if possible

Tags: r, scrape, rvest

I am trying to scrape the table from this URL:
"https://hutdb.net/17/players"
I have spent a lot of time learning rvest and using selectorgadget, however whenever I try to get an output I always get the same error (Character(0)).

```
library(rvest)
library(magrittr)

url   <- read_html("https://hutdb.net/17/players")
table <- url %>%
  html_nodes("td") %>%
  html_text()
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The data is dynamically loaded, and cannot be retrieved directly from the html. But, looking at "Network", we can find a nicely formatted JSON at https://hutdb.net/ajax/stats.php?year=17&page=0&selected=OVR&sort=DESC

Answer (score 0):

The data is dynamically loaded, and cannot be retrieved directly from the html. But, looking at "Network" in Chrome DevTools for instance, we can find a nicely formatted JSON at https://hutdb.net/ajax/stats.php?year=17&page=0&selected=OVR&sort=DESC

```
library(jsonlite)
dat <- fromJSON("https://hutdb.net/ajax/stats.php?year=17&page=0&selected=OVR&sort=DESC")
```

Output looks like:

```
#     results aOVR    id League Year Card Team              Player Position Type Shoots  HGT
# 1      6308 6308  <NA>   <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>                <NA>     <NA> <NA>   <NA> <NA>
# 2      <NA> 2030 11782    NHL   17  MOV  OTT       Erik Karlsson       RD  OFD  Right  6'0
# 3      <NA> 2060 11785    NHL   17  MOV  TBL       Victor Hedman       LD  TWD   Left  6'6
# 4      <NA> 2008 11791    NHL   17  MOV  CHI        Patrick Kane       RW  SNP   Left 5'11
# 5      <NA> 2058 13845    NHL   17  SCE  ANA        Ryan Getzlaf        C  PWF  Right  6'4
# 6      <NA> 2074 11824    NHL   17  MOV  BOS       Brad Marchand       LW  TWF   Left  5'9
# 7      <NA> 2008 11829    NHL   17  MOV  EDM      Connor McDavid        C  PLY   Left  6'2
# 8      <NA> 2048 11840    NHL   17  MOV  WSH   Nicklas Backstrom        C  PLY   Left  6'1
# 9      <NA> 2058 11841    NHL   17  MOV  PIT       Sidney Crosby        C  PLY   Left 5'11
# 10     <NA> 2065 13644    NHL   17 TOTY  WPG        Patrik Laine       RW  TWF  Right  6'3
# 11     <NA> 2008 13645    NHL   17 TOTY  EDM      Connor McDavid        C  PLY   Left  6'2
# 12     <NA> 2039 13680    NHL   17 TOTY  LAK        Drew Doughty       RD  TWD  Right  6'1
# 13     <NA> 2063 13689    NHL   17 TOTY  BOS    Patrice Bergeron        C  TWF  Right  6'2
```

Comment: This is a good start, however this seems to only bring records in from the first page, How can I extract data from all the pages (the entire table)?

Comment: Not sure. Maybe scrape pages one by one with the `page=` parameter in the URL. When scraping, be gentle on the server and add offset times (`Sys.sleep()`) between requests

Comment: yes I ended up looping through page numbers and getting all the data. Thanks for your help.